# How to insert nested UDT types

Tags: cassandra, user-defined-type

I have all these case classes :-

```
case class Role(id:UUID,
                roleName:String,
                description:Option[String],
                isVisible:Boolean,
                isDefault:Option[Boolean],
                contacts:Contact_Permissions,
                status:String) 

 case class 
Contact_Permissions(name:String,description:String,Type:String,permission: 
   Seq[Contact_Permission])

case class 
Contact_Permission(name:String,Types:String,options:Option[List[String]],value:List[String])
```

and these Types:-

```
CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS myuser.contact_permission(
name text,
types text,
options list<text>,
value list<text>
)

CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXIXSTS myuser.contact_permissions(
name text,
description text,
types text,
permission frozen<contact_permission>
)
```

And my table is table:-

```
        """
          |CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myuser.roles(
          |role_id uuid,
          |role_name text,
          |description text,
          |is_visible  boolean,
          |is_default  boolean,
          |contacts_permission frozen<contact_permission>,
          |status text
          |)
          |""".stripMargin)
```

I have made codecs for both types:-

```
class PermissionCodec(private val innerCodec: TypeCodec[UDTValue],
                  javaType: Class[Contact_Permission])
  extends TypeCodec[Contact_Permission](innerCodec.getCqlType, javaType) {


  private val userType: UserType = innerCodec.getCqlType.asInstanceOf[UserType]

  override def serialize(value: Contact_Permission,
                         protocolVersion: ProtocolVersion): ByteBuffer =
    innerCodec.serialize(toUDTValue(value), protocolVersion)

  override def deserialize(bytes: ByteBuffer,
                           protocolVersion: ProtocolVersion): Contact_Permission =
    toFilter(innerCodec.deserialize(bytes, protocolVersion))

  override def parse(value: String): Contact_Permission =
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty || value == null) null
    else toFilter(innerCodec.parse(value))

  override def format(value: Contact_Permission): String =
    if (value == null) null else innerCodec.format(toUDTValue(value))

  protected def toFilter(value: UDTValue): Contact_Permission =
    if (value == null) null
    else new Contact_Permission(value.getString("name"),
      value.getString("Types"),
      Some(value.getList("options", classOf[String]).toList),
      value.getList("value", classOf[String]).toList
    )


  protected def toUDTValue(value: Contact_Permission): UDTValue =
    if (value == null) null
    else
      userType
        .newValue()
        .setString("name", value.name)
        .setString("Types", value.Types)
        .setList("options", value.options.get)
        .setList("value", value.value)

}

class Contact_Permission_Codec(private val innerCodec: TypeCodec[UDTValue],
                         javaType: Class[Contact_Permissions])
  extends TypeCodec[Contact_Permissions](innerCodec.getCqlType, javaType) {

  private val userType: UserType = innerCodec.getCqlType.asInstanceOf[UserType]

  override def serialize(value: Contact_Permissions,
                         protocolVersion: ProtocolVersion): ByteBuffer =
    innerCodec.serialize(toUDTValue(value), protocolVersion)

  override def deserialize(bytes: ByteBuffer,
                           protocolVersion: ProtocolVersion): Contact_Permissions =
    toFilter(innerCodec.deserialize(bytes, protocolVersion))

  override def parse(value: String): Contact_Permissions =
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty || value == null) null
    else toFilter(innerCodec.parse(value))

  override def format(value: Contact_Permissions): String =
    if (value == null) null else innerCodec.format(toUDTValue(value))

  protected def toFilter(value: UDTValue): Contact_Permissions =
    if (value == null) null
    else new Contact_Permissions(value.getString("name"),
      value.getString("description"),
      value.getString("Type"),
      value.getList("permission",classOf[Contact_Permission]).toList
    )


  protected def toUDTValue(value: Contact_Permissions): UDTValue =
    if (value == null) null
    else
      userType
        .newValue()
        .setString("name",value.name)
        .setString("description",value.description)
        .setString("Type",value.Type)
        .setList("permission",value.permission)
}
```

My question is How to set values in these nested UDT.

any help pls ??

Comment: This question is better for StackOverflow than to the `dba.stackexcange.com`

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier to use [Object Mapper](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/object_mapper/) that is a separate part of the DataStax Java driver - in this case you can easily map UDT and table into case classes. Something like this (I wrote [an article on using Object Mapper with Scala](https://www.datastax.com/blog/using-object-mapper-scala) - it's too long to past it here completely):

```scala
@UDT(name = "scala_udt")
case class UdtCaseClass(id: Integer, @(Field @field)(name = "t") text: String) {
  def this() {
    this(0, "")
  }
}

@Table(name = "scala_test_udt")
case class TableObjectCaseClassWithUDT(@(PartitionKey @field) id: Integer,
                                      udt: UdtCaseClass) {
  def this() {
    this(0, UdtCaseClass(0, ""))
  }
}
```